# Is a multilayer neural net of 2 neurons just the same like 1 neuron

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

AND logic and OR logic can be solved by just 1 neuron. However, XOR logic needs a neural network of 3 neurons in 2 layers:

```
(neuron1)\
          \
           +----- (neuron3)
          /
(neuron2)/
```

Consider this form of neural network:

```
(neuron1) ------- (neuron2)
```

Is this kind of neural network with just 2 neurons connecting to each other able to solve anything better than just 1 single neuron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 neurons can be more powerful than 1 neuron.

For example consider two neurons with the standard [rectifier nonlinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) max(0,x).

Let the input be x.

The first neuron computes y=max(0,x)

The second neuron computes z=max(0,1-y)

The picture plots y (green),1-y (red),z (blue) against x.

[image]

This shows how two neurons both using a simple rectifier can construct a more complicated saturating nonlinearity (represented by the blue line).

There is no way to produce the blue line with a single rectifying neuron operating on a single output (because all such outputs have at most two linear segments, and our z output has three linear segments).

Comment: how about a single neuron with this activation function: f(x) = 1 if x<0, 1-x if 0<=x<=1, 0 if x>1